# Storing base java project inside child project jar (maven, docker)

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker, spring-cloud

Thanks for having a look at this!
Max

In the future I'm going to building lots of microservices that are all based upon the same parent java project. These microservices are all going to be using spring cloud and docker.
I currently have the base java project and a child project. The main for each microservices should be inherited from the parent project. 
Up till now I've been using

```
    mvn clean package assembly:single
```

for building the jar for the microservice so that the parent is store inside the jar. Then to run

```
    java -cp MicroService.jar path.to.parent.Main
```

Which is working fine. I'm sure it's not the best way to go about it and I'd love any advice about improvements.

My problem now is that I want to use `docker:build`

```
    mvn clean package docker:build
```

After packaging the microservice using docker:build, how do I specify a path to the parent project's Main since the parent project is no longer being stored in the jar made from `docker:build`.

### Microservice (child)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>0.0.1</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>micro-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->

    </parent>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springframework.maven.release</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
      <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.10</version>
      <configuration>
        <imageName>example</imageName>
        <baseImage>java</baseImage>
        <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
        <!-- copy the service's jar file from target into the root directory of the image --> 
        <resources>
           <resource>
             <targetPath>/</targetPath>
             <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
             <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
           </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
       .
       <!-- Removed other dependancies to save space -->
       .
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>parent-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html

## Solved

Thanks to @M. Deinum comment.

I changed to pom.xml to

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>0.0.1</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>micro-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->

    </parent>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springframework.maven.release</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
       .
       <!-- Removed other dependancies to save space -->
       .
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>parent-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

I now just run

```
    mvn clean package
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the assembly plugin but the spring-boot-maven plugin which does exactly what you want. So basically your pom (and project setup) have been flawed from the start. When done like that you can simply do `java -jar your-jar.jar` nothing more to do. Basically by introducing the assembly plugin and working around spring boot you made things more complex.

Comment: @M.Deinum that fixed it :) Thank you for your help!!